# Using braintree on mobile app developed by C# and Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, braintree

Can I use `braintree` on mobile apps developed by `C#` and `Xamarin`?
I found old topics talking about that. Is this problem solved now? Is there any other way to get paid on PayPal like braintree for these type of apps?

Comment: It's an API that you call over HTTP, so the answer is "yes you can use it".

Comment: You can create a binding for their iOS and Android libraries for use in Xamarin.  Or you can use their REST API.

Comment: @Ali Mohamed were you able to use the Bindings?

Answer (score 3):

To use the braintree SDK, you can generate the DLL files with the help of these bindings: https://github.com/Clusterize/Xamarin-Braintree.iOS-Bindings